# Specific URL into conditional tag

Tags: blogger

I have this link:

```
<a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + "search/?q=label:" + data:label.name + "&amp;max-results=6&amp;by-date=true"'><data:label.name/></a>
```

And I want to put it into this conditional tag where is the `data:label.url`:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:label.url'>
```

I try this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + "search/?q=label:" + data:label.name + "&amp;max-results=6&amp;by-date=true""'>
```

But with no luck!!! Any idea?

---

The untouched part of code:

```
<b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;label-size label-size-&quot; + data:label.cssSize'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:label.url'>
            <span expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection'><data:label.name/></span>
        <b:else/>
            <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:showFreqNumbers'>
            <span class='label-count' dir='ltr'>(<data:label.count/>)</span>
        </b:if>
    </span>
</b:loop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posts with specific labels you can use this condition ([this article](http://mystady.com/2011/05/7-blogger-page-types-analysis-code.html#label-page-type) must help).

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot; and data:blog.searchLabel'>...</b:if>
```